# Замена SimpleDateFormat на Maс OS X  в Java.

Tags: mac, java, swing

Программа написанная на Java + Swing вываливается под маком, там где пытается использовать SimpleDateFormat. Есть ли его аналог? Или просто юзать DateFormat?

Вот код:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm | dd.MM.YYYY");
```

Comment: ошибки какие выдает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать в паттерне `SimpleDateFormat` вывод временной зоны (timezone) - знак `z`, иногда проблема может быть в том, что JVM неверно парсит таймзону получаемую из оси.

Comment: Ошибка крылась в другом, но спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было вот так, так как символ "|" используется в служебных целях.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm '|' dd.MM.YYYY");
```